# Android: How to show .pdf file in application with vertical scroll?

Tags: android, pdf

I am stuck, I have pdf file and I want to show in my app view with only vertical scroll. I have gone through eBookDroid, vudroid etc. but disappointed.

Comment: When working with PDFs in android, I found it much easier to just use an external app to display the PDF. Granted, this was about a year ago, and your options may have gotten better since then.

Comment: @Vitor M. Barbosa, you are right but how to integrate in my app layout where i want to show .pdf file.

Comment: What do you mean by "disappointed"? Did you look at MuPDF? http://www.mupdf.com/

Comment: @fasteque, I have looked MuPDF but this is also a pdf reader, I want to show pdf in my own app's layout. Hope you have better idea.

Comment: If you download the code on their website you can build your pdf reader as part of your app. Their reader is like a demo of what you can do with their library. Please be aware that it still doesn't support all the annotation types if you need them.

Comment: take look http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-pdf-reader-open-source-code.html